# decision tree for features which are vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

Problem -I  want to train a decision tree for classification task. However, for each data point, my input features are not values but vectors. Also my output is a vector.

Sample data point's input feature:

```
[[0.33,0.33,0,0,0.33], [1,1,0,0,1], 1, [1,0,1], [3,2,0,0,1]]
```

And output:

```
[1,1,0,0,1]
```

I tried using `DecisionTreeClassifier` from sklearn. It did not work saying:

```
ValueError: Number of labels=5 does not match number of samples=1
```

Are features allowed to be vectors? Or do they have to be values?
Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The problem is that each nested list in your `features` should have 5 elements.